# Can abstract class be added as subclass to HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, abstract-class

I have a method which takes

```
    exampleMethod(Map<String, Number> exMap).
```

Can I call this method with subclass of Number like Integer or Long? So the method class would be

```
    A a = new A();
    a.exampleMethod(Map<"String, Integer"> intMap);
```

Thanks

Comment: No.  You must convert the method signature to `exampleMethod(Map<String, ? extends Number> exMap)` to support non-exactly-`Number` map value types.

Answer (score 7):

no, in order to do that you need the method signature to be

```
exampleMethod(Map<String, ? extends Number> exMap)
```

of course, then you won't be able to add any values to the map, just read them.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with jtahlborn's version, alternatively, you can do it as

```
<T extends Number> void exampleMethod(Map<String, T> exMap) {
}
```